# Pass variable from Batch to VBS

Tags: variables, batch-file, parameters, vbscript

Hi I am trying to pass a user input variable from a BAT to VBS script

Im sure this can be done in VBS but the user "Filename" input is used also later in the BAT file

As you can see the **"FileName"** variable in the .bat section needs to be passed into the VBS script for the file path ("C:\Users\bob\Documents\ **%FileName%"**)

**.Bat**

```
set /p FileName= Enter Filename Including Extention e.g. test.xlsx
```

**VBS:**

```
Set xlObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\%FileName%")
'turn off screen alerts
xlObj.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'loop through sheets
For Each Worksheet In xlFile.Worksheets 
'change sheet to desired worksheet name
If Worksheet.Name = "Old111" Then
Worksheet.Name = "NewName111"
End if
Next
'save, close, then quit
xlFile.Close True
xlObj.Quit
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend passing information from one script to another via environment variables. I suppose you're running the VBScript from the batch script? In that case you could simply pass the filename as an argument to the VBScript:

```
set /p "FileName= Enter Filename Including Extention (e.g. test.xlsx): "
cscript.exe //NoLogo C:\path\to\your.vbs "%FileName%"
```

In the VBScript you process the argument like this:

```
filename = WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)
```

You could also use a name argument:

```
set /p "FileName= Enter Filename Including Extention (e.g. test.xlsx): "
cscript.exe //NoLogo C:\path\to\your.vbs /filename:"%FileName%"
```

with the argument evaluation in your VBScript looking like this:

```
filename = WScript.Arguments.Named("filename")
```

Comment: Any reason to avoid environment variables to pass data? I know Arguments collection is here to handle arguments, but, when the data is in a environment variable, why to avoid them?

Comment: @MCND Arguments are easier to handle IMO, because that way it's clear what information is passed from where to where. Using environment variables for transporting information from one process to another always feels side-channel-ish to me.

Comment: Be aware that the named/unnamed properties are only available using WSH 5.6 and above (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302057.aspx). You'd think that no one uses Windows 2000 anymore, but sadly they still do (and they also post questions here too!)

Comment: How do i use the varaible in this string?                         Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\FileName")

Comment: @user2770724 Like this: `Set xlFile = xlObj.WorkBooks.Open("C:\Users\xxx\Documents\" & filename)`.

Comment: EDIT: SOLVED!!! Ignore post >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>I get this error, doesnt seem to be dragging in the varaible from the batch. Shall play around a little more.............. C:\Project\xxx\renameexcel.vbs(5, 1) Microsoft Excel: 'C:\Projects\xxxx\ImportFile\' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify tha t the file location is correct.

Comment: @user2770724 `filename` seems to be empty in your code. Please update your question with the code that raises the error (both batch and VBScript).

Comment: I used your first method and it worked using a name argument didnt seem to work. SOLVED thanks Ansgar!

Answer (score 0):

almost everything can be done with vbs. you don't need a batch

to get user input from vbs, you can use stdin. copy from [here](http://ss64.com/vb/stdoutread.html).

```
' Read a single line into a variable
Dim strMyName
WScript.StdOut.Write("Enter Your full Name>")
WScript.StdIn.Read(0)
strMyName = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
WScript.StdOut.Write(strMyName)
```

Comment: Needs to be done with both Bat and VBS, as BAT has a ton of code already that uses the FileName Variable

Answer (score 0):

```
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%FileName%")
```