# Calling two scripts from batch file run asynchronously

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, telnet

I have batch file which gets user input, tranfers the input to a vb script.

```
set /p "whichPort= Which port do you want to reset:" 
start /b "" cscript.exe //NoLogo loginInXyplex.vbs /portname:"%whichPort%"
```

Then a telnet session is exceuted from within the batch file, followed by the exection of the same script file in order to issue commands in the telnet session.

```
telnet.exe 192.120.187.35 2000

REM run the script

 cscript loginInXyplex.vbs
```

When in the telnet session it appears the two scripts are running at the same time as the conmmands are out of synch so cannot log on properly

This is my first vb script so I could be missing somethong obivious, so i  have  included all source code :

Batch File:

```
@echo off
cls
echo.
echo Welcome to Xyplex Server Port Reset
echo.
pause
echo.
set /p whichXplex= Which Xyplex server is your device connected too: 1 or 2 ?
echo.
set /p "whichPort= Which port do you want to reset:" 
echo  Sending port "%whichPort%" to script file
echo.
pause
rem send using strat /b so we open script file on same command line window 
start /b "" cscript.exe //NoLogo loginInXyplex.vbs /portname:"%whichPort%"
echo.
echo Conencting to Xyplex "%whichXplex%"
pause
if  "%whichXyplex%" == "1" (
  REM COnnecting to xyplex one IP:Socket
echo.
  echo Connecting to Xpyplex %whichXyplex%...
   telnet.exe 192.120.187.35 2000
 REM run the script
 cscript loginInXyplex.vbs

) ELSE (
rem   ^ missing spaces in )ELSE(
  echo Conencting to xyplex %whichXyplex%....
 telnet.exe 193.120.187.245 2000
REM run the script in same widow wuth start /b 
cscript loginInXyplex.vbs
)
```

Script:

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
OBJECT.SendKeys"{ENTER}"
OBJECT.SendKeys "access{ENTER}"
WScript.sleep 50
OBJECT.SendKeys "access{ENTER}"
OBJECT.SendKeys "SET PRIV{ENTER}"
OBJECT.SendKeys "system{ENTER}"
OBJECT.SendKeys "sh po all{ENTER}"
OBJECT.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
' source heer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013428/pass-variable-from-batch-to-vbs

port = WScript.Arguments.Named.Item("portname")

OBJECT.SendKeys port

OBJECT.SendKeys  "Port number selected is: " & port


OBJECT.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

OBJECT.SendKeys "Port reset....logging off...{ENTER}"
OBJECT.SendKeys "SET NOPRIV {ENTER}"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
OBJECT.SendKeys "Quit"
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It's way easier to use the freeware "Telnet Scripting Tool". It's even proposed by SS64.com at the bottom of this page: http://ss64.com/nt/telnet.html

Comment: What is the difference when running a script : start /b "" cscript.exe //NoLogo loginInXyplex.vbs /portname:"%whichPort%"
and cscript loginInXyplex.vbs

I tried removing teh latter and the script did not appear to excute.